# Which C++ compilers use the access specifier in name mangling?

Tags: c++, name-mangling, access-specifier

I know MSVC does, and GCC doesn't?
What about the others?

Comment: Why would this matter to you? And I didn't realise that MSVC did - I don't think it used to, and I can't see any reason why it should.

Comment: It determines whether you can change the access of a function while still maintaining binary compatibility.

Comment: @Neil: to foil people trying to use `#define private public` to help with debugging.

Comment: @Mike Not something I've ever done.

Comment: @mmutz Whenever I see the dread words "binary compatibility" I always get the feeling that the person using them does not know what they mean. You may, of course, be an exception.

Comment: @Neil: it's probably not something you'd ever want to do in MSVC, with its nice graphical debugger. On some platforms, `printf` and access violations are the best debugging tools available.

Comment: @Mike I haven't used MSVC since 6.0.

Comment: @Mike: Isn't it undefined behaviour to use a keyword as macro identifier no matter what name mangling does?

Comment: @sellibitze: it certainly is; only do it if you know how your compiler/linker behaves, and never leave it in production code.

Answer (score 2):

@Neil: MSVC does: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/08/12/some-thoughts-on-binary-compatibility/

EDIT: sorry, i meant to reply.

Comment: Interesting link. Those crazy guys at MS, eh? One suspects too many interns with too much time on their hands.

Comment: Sounds like to many architects trying to justify there salary :-0

Answer (score 0):

This probably not only depends on compiler but also on platform. ARM name mangling scheme does not use access modifiers to mangle names. Itanium does (gcc follows this one). Microsoft as far as I know is the only one to use it on it's own scheme.